# How to make sure that the user of the application is moving

Tags: flutter, dart

i try to check if the user is moving or not

i tried geolocator plugin to get current location and last location then calculate the distance but wasn't accurate on real device

and tried location plugin with latlong to get distance but was the same.

also i was thinking what if the user moved from location 1 and then come back to the same location 1 he moved but the calculating of the distance will tell he didn't

Is there another way to check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use any plugin which can give you current speed, if your `speed > 0`, user is moving else not.

```
someListener((location) {
  if(location.speed > 0) // you can use change it to 0.5 or 1
    // user is moving
  else 
    // not moving
});
```